# Fibonacci series in iterated remainders

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider two numbers $N$ and $n< N$ that are coprime, i.e. $gcd(N,n)=1$.

Consider the following algorithm. Start with $N_0 = k_0\,n_0 + r_0$ with $n_0 \leq N_0/2$. Iteratively set $n_{i+1} = r_i$ and $N_{i+1} = N_i - n_i$ as long as $r_i > 0$. Since $r_{i+1} < r_i$ this procedure must come to an end. My main question is: **How many iterations are needed until $r_i = 0$ for a given pair of numbers $N,n$?** What does the number $\mu(N,n)$ of iterations depend on? Can it be given in a closed formula?

The smallest pairs with $\mu(N,n) = 1,2,\dots,12$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
N_{0} : n_{0} & \mathbf{5:2} & \mathbf{8:3} & \mathbf{13:5} & \mathbf{21:8} & \mathbf{34:13} & \mathbf{55:21} & \mathbf{89:34} & \mathbf{144:55} & \mathbf{233:89} & \mathbf{377:144} & \mathbf{610:233} & \mathbf{987:377}\\ \hline
k_{0}\ \ r_{0} & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5 & 2\ \ 8 & 2\ \ 13 & 2\ \ 21 & 2\ \ 34 & 2\ \ 55 & 2\ \ 89 & 2\ \ 144 & 2\ \ 233\\ \hline
N_{0}-n_{0} & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 55 & 89 & 144 & 233 & 377 & 610\\ \hline
N_{1} : n_{1} & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5 & 21:8 & 34:13 & 55:21 & 89:34 & 144:55 & 233:89 & 377:144 & 610:233\\ \hline
k_{1}\ \ r_{1} & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5 & 2\ \ 8 & 2\ \ 13 & 2\ \ 21 & 2\ \ 34 & 2\ \ 55 & 2\ \ 89 & 2\ \ 144\\ \hline
N_{1}-n_{1} &  & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 55 & 89 & 144 & 233 & 377\\ \hline
N_{2} : n_{2} &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5 & 21:8 & 34:13 & 55:21 & 89:34 & 144:55 & 233:89 & 377:144\\ \hline
k_{2}\ \ r_{2} &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5 & 2\ \ 8 & 2\ \ 13 & 2\ \ 21 & 2\ \ 34 & 2\ \ 55 & 2\ \ 89\\ \hline
N_{2}-n_{2} &  &  & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 55 & 89 & 144 & 233\\ \hline
N_{3} : n_{3} &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5 & 21:8 & 34:13 & 55:21 & 89:34 & 144:55 & 233:89\\ \hline
k_{3}\ \ r_{3} &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5 & 2\ \ 8 & 2\ \ 13 & 2\ \ 21 & 2\ \ 34 & 2\ \ 55\\ \hline
N_{3}-n_{3} &  &  &  & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 55 & 89 & 144\\ \hline
N_{4} : n_{4} &  &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5 & 21:8 & 34:13 & 55:21 & 89:34 & 144:55\\ \hline
k_{4}\ \ r_{4} &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5 & 2\ \ 8 & 2\ \ 13 & 2\ \ 21 & 2\ \ 34\\ \hline
N_{4}-n_{4} &  &  &  &  & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 55 & 89\\ \hline
N_{5} : n_{5} &  &  &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5 & 21:8 & 34:13 & 55:21 & 89:34\\ \hline
k_{5}\ \ r_{5} &  &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5 & 2\ \ 8 & 2\ \ 13 & 2\ \ 21\\ \hline
N_{5}-n_{5} &  &  &  &  &  & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 55\\ \hline
N_{6} : n_{6} &  &  &  &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5 & 21:8 & 34:13 & 55:21\\ \hline
k_{6}\ \ r_{6} &  &  &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5 & 2\ \ 8 & 2\ \ 13\\ \hline
N_{6}-n_{6} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34\\ \hline
N_{7} : n_{7} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5 & 21:8 & 34:13\\ \hline
k_{7}\ \ r_{7} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5 & 2\ \ 8\\ \hline
N_{7}-n_{7} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21\\ \hline
N_{8} : n_{8} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5 & 21:8\\ \hline
k_{8}\ \ r_{8} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 5\\ \hline
N_{8}-n_{8} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13\\ \hline
N_{9} : n_{9} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3 & 13:5\\ \hline
k_{9}\ \ r_{9} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3\\ \hline
N_{9}-n_{9} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3 & 5 & 8\\ \hline
N_{10} : n_{10} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2 & 8:3\\ \hline
k_{10}\ \ r_{10} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2\\ \hline
N_{10}-n_{10} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3 & 5\\ \hline
N_{11} : n_{11} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:1 & 5:2\\ \hline
k_{11}\ \ r_{11} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0 & 2\ \ 1\\ \hline
N_{11}-n_{11} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3\\ \hline
N_{12} : n_{12} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:1\\ \hline
k_{12}\ \ r_{12} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3\ \ 0\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

In these cases the last non-zero remainder is $1$, the same as the Euclidean algorithm would yield as the greatest common divisor.

Specific questions:

1. Given a number $\mu_0$. How to calculate the smallest pair $N,n$ with $\mu(N,n) = \mu_0$, but not by brut force but algorithmically? For $\mu_0 \leq 12$ these pairs are given in the table above (found by brut force).
2. What is the asymptotic behaviour of $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \max\{\mu(N,n)\}_{n < N}$?
3. How can it be explained that the numbers $N_i, n_i,r_i$ in the table above all come as (shifted) Fibonacci series?

Here are some other examples:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
N_{0} : n_{0} & \mathbf{5:2} & \mathbf{12:5} & \mathbf{25:11} & \mathbf{45:19} & \mathbf{91:40} & \mathbf{122:51} & \mathbf{215:64} & \mathbf{334:151} & \mathbf{616:197} & \mathbf{634:189}\\ \hline
k_{0}\ \ r_{0} & 2\ \ 1 & 2\ \ 2 & 2\ \ 3 & 2\ \ 7 & 2\ \ 11 & 2\ \ 20 & 3\ \ 23 & 2\ \ 32 & 3\ \ 25 & 3\ \ 67\\ \hline
N_{0}-n_{0} & 3 & 7 & 14 & 26 & 51 & 71 & 151 & 183 & 419 & 445\\ \hline
N_{1} : n_{1} & 3:1 & 7:2 & 14:3 & 26:7 & 51:11 & 71:20 & 151:23 & 183:32 & 419:25 & 445:67\\ \hline
k_{1}\ \ r_{1} & 3\ \ 0 & 3\ \ 1 & 4\ \ 2 & 3\ \ 5 & 4\ \ 7 & 3\ \ 11 & 6\ \ 13 & 5\ \ 23 & 16\ \ 19 & 6\ \ 43\\ \hline
N_{1}-n_{1} &  & 5 & 11 & 19 & 40 & 51 & 128 & 151 & 394 & 378\\ \hline
N_{2} : n_{2} &  & 5:1 & 11:2 & 19:5 & 40:7 & 51:11 & 128:13 & 151:23 & 394:19 & 378:43\\ \hline
k_{2}\ \ r_{2} &  & 5\ \ 0 & 5\ \ 1 & 3\ \ 4 & 5\ \ 5 & 4\ \ 7 & 9\ \ 11 & 6\ \ 13 & 20\ \ 14 & 8\ \ 34\\ \hline
N_{2}-n_{2} &  &  & 9 & 14 & 33 & 40 & 115 & 128 & 375 & 335\\ \hline
N_{3} : n_{3} &  &  & 9:1 & 14:4 & 33:5 & 40:7 & 115:11 & 128:13 & 375:14 & 335:34\\ \hline
k_{3}\ \ r_{3} &  &  & 9\ \ 0 & 3\ \ 2 & 6\ \ 3 & 5\ \ 5 & 10\ \ 5 & 9\ \ 11 & 26\ \ 11 & 9\ \ 29\\ \hline
N_{3}-n_{3} &  &  &  & 10 & 28 & 33 & 104 & 115 & 361 & 301\\ \hline
N_{4} : n_{4} &  &  &  & 10:2 & 28:3 & 33:5 & 104:5 & 115:11 & 361:11 & 301:29\\ \hline
k_{4}\ \ r_{4} &  &  &  & 5\ \ 0 & 9\ \ 1 & 6\ \ 3 & 20\ \ 4 & 10\ \ 5 & 32\ \ 9 & 10\ \ 11\\ \hline
N_{4}-n_{4} &  &  &  &  & 25 & 28 & 99 & 104 & 350 & 272\\ \hline
N_{5} : n_{5} &  &  &  &  & 25:1 & 28:3 & 99:4 & 104:5 & 350:9 & 272:11\\ \hline
k_{5}\ \ r_{5} &  &  &  &  & 25\ \ 0 & 9\ \ 1 & 24\ \ 3 & 20\ \ 4 & 38\ \ 8 & 24\ \ 8\\ \hline
N_{5}-n_{5} &  &  &  &  &  & 25 & 95 & 99 & 341 & 261\\ \hline
N_{6} : n_{6} &  &  &  &  &  & 25:1 & 95:3 & 99:4 & 341:8 & 261:8\\ \hline
k_{6}\ \ r_{6} &  &  &  &  &  & 25\ \ 0 & 31\ \ 2 & 24\ \ 3 & 42\ \ 5 & 32\ \ 5\\ \hline
N_{6}-n_{6} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 92 & 95 & 333 & 253\\ \hline
N_{7} : n_{7} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 92:2 & 95:3 & 333:5 & 253:5\\ \hline
k_{7}\ \ r_{7} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 46\ \ 0 & 31\ \ 2 & 66\ \ 3 & 50\ \ 3\\ \hline
N_{7}-n_{7} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 92 & 328 & 248\\ \hline
N_{8} : n_{8} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 92:2 & 328:3 & 248:3\\ \hline
k_{8}\ \ r_{8} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 46\ \ 0 & 109\ \ 1 & 82\ \ 2\\ \hline
N_{8}-n_{8} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 325 & 245\\ \hline
N_{9} : n_{9} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 325:1 & 245:2\\ \hline
k_{9}\ \ r_{9} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 325\ \ 0 & 122\ \ 1\\ \hline
N_{9}-n_{9} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 243\\ \hline
N_{10} : n_{10} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 243:1\\ \hline
k_{10}\ \ r_{10} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 243\ \ 0\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Note that the last non-zero remainder is not always $1$ even though $N$ and $n$ are coprime. So the algorithm yields different results (last non-zero remainder) than the Euclidean algorithm. What does the last non-zero remainder **mean**?

Comment: This process is closed related to the Euclidean algorithm for gcd: it uses subtraction instead of division, but that does not make a difference for Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @lhf: You mean "closely related"?

Comment: @lhf: In any case, all pairs $N_0,n_0$ are coprime, and so are all $N_i, n_i$.

Comment: Yes, I mean "closely related"

Comment: @lhf: The Fibonacci part seems clear to you. What about the other questions (if I may ask)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency

Comment: @lhf: Thanks. When the Euclidean algorithm gives the gcd of two numbers and the number of steps required for completion is never more than five times the number h of base-10 digits of the smaller number b: What does my algorithm give, and does the same upper bound hold here? (It does not give the gcd, because this is always 1.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133702/discussion-between-hans-peter-stricker-and-lhf).